# Set skin on extended GridView object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to extend the GridView Control which has worked fine all apart from applying a theme.

The class is defined as below.

```
[Themeable(true)]
public class TestCustControl : GridView
```

I have tried setting the SkinId in the constructor as:

```
SkinID = "GridViewNew";
```

But this hasn't worked.

I want to set it within the control preferably so it appears the same throughout the site. I have also tried setting it in the aspx without any luck like:

```
<uc1:TestCustControl runat="server" id="GridViewMeterView" 
Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="GridViewMeterView_RowDataBound" 
Visible="false" OnSorting="GridViewMeterView_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewMeterView_PageIndexChanging" 
SkinID="GridViewNew" />
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the skin whith the name of your new custom control

```
<uc1:TestCustControl SkinID="GridViewNew" Runat="server" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" PageSize="50" GridLines="None" CellPadding="4" width="100%"  CssClass="GridViewStyle" >
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle"/>
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridViewSelectedRowStyle" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridViewPagerStyle" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="GridViewFooterStyle" />
</uc1:TestCustControl>

<asp:GridView SkinID="GridViewNew" Runat="server" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" PageSize="20" GridLines="None" CellPadding="4" width="100%" CssClass="GridViewStyle" >
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle"/>
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridViewSelectedRowStyle" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridViewPagerStyle" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="GridViewFooterStyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```